# Spring Boot+MyBatis mapping Timestamp to LocalDateTime does not work

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis, ibatis

> When I'm trying to get Purchase instance(by id, or from User) I have
>   next error:

```
org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: No constructor found in com.lisonn.mybatis.entity.Purchase matching [java.lang.Long, java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer, java.sql.Timestamp, java.lang.Integer]
```

> But Timestamp is supposed to be automatically converted to
>   LocalDateTime, as I set in the PurchaseResultMap(I tried to use
>   'result' for timing field, also I set jdbcType as TIMESTAMP, nothing
>   helped).
>
> What's the problem with converting timestamp to LocalDateTime? I'm
>   using Spring Boot 1.5.9, MyBatis Spring Boot Starter 1.3.1
>
> Thanks is advance! Below are my project configurations.

application.yaml:

```
...
mybatis:
  mapper-locations: classpath:mappers/**
  type-aliases-package: com.lisonn.mybatis.entity
  type-handlers-package: org.apache.ibatis.type.handler
```

PurchaseMapper.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE mapper
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.lisonn.mybatis.mapper.PurchaseMapper">
    <resultMap id="PurchaseResultMap" type="com.lisonn.mybatis.entity.Purchase">
        <id column="id" property="id" />
        <result column="naming" property="naming" />
        <result column="price" property="price" />
        <association column="timing" property="timing" javaType="java.time.LocalDateTime"/>
        <association property="user" column="user_id" javaType="com.lisonn.mybatis.entity.User"
                     select="selectUserForPurchase"/>
    </resultMap>

    <select id="selectUserForPurchase"
            parameterType="java.lang.Integer"
            resultType="com.lisonn.mybatis.entity.User">
        SELECT *
        FROM
        mybatis.users
        WHERE
        id = #{user_id}
    </select>

    <select id="findOne"
            parameterType="java.lang.Integer"
            resultMap="PurchaseResultMap"
            resultType="com.lisonn.mybatis.entity.Purchase"
    >
        SELECT *
        FROM mybatis.purchase
        where id = #{id}
    </select>

</mapper>
```

UserMapper.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE mapper
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.lisonn.mybatis.mapper.UserMapper">
    <resultMap id="UserResultMap" type="com.lisonn.mybatis.entity.User">
        <id column="id" property="id" />
        <result column="name" property="name" />
        <result column="email" property="email" />
        <collection property="purchases" ofType="com.lisonn.mybatis.entity.Purchase"
                    column="id" select="selectUserPurchases" />
    </resultMap>

    <select id="findAllUsers" resultMap="UserResultMap">
        select id, name, email from users
    </select>

    <select id="findUserById" resultMap="UserResultMap">
        select id, name, email from users WHERE id=#{id}
    </select>

    <select id="findUsersWhereNameLike" resultMap="UserResultMap" parameterType="String">
        select id, name, email from users WHERE id=#{id}
    </select>

    <select id="selectUserPurchases"
            resultMap="com.lisonn.mybatis.mapper.PurchaseMapper.PurchaseResultMap"
            parameterType="java.lang.Integer"
            resultType="com.lisonn.mybatis.entity.Purchase">
        SELECT *
        FROM
        mybatis.purchase
        WHERE
        user_id = #{id}
    </select>

    <insert id="insertUser" parameterType="User" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="id">
        insert into users(name,email) values(#{name},#{email})
    </insert>
</mapper>
```

User:

```
public class User
{
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private List<Purchase> purchases;
    ...
}
```

Purchase:

```
public class Purchase {

    private Long id;
    private String naming;
    private Integer price;
    private LocalDateTime timing;
    private Integer userId;
    private User user;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi @Vlad, I have a similar problem. Did you find a solution to your problem? Thanks.